# Python or R! - draw histograms for specified raster files

Tags: python, r, statistics, histogram

I have two raster files (one with big cell size and second with much smaller.)
I have written a Python script which splits these files into pieces limited by bigger cells.

Now I want to draw a histogram for cell values and add value (for example as a line) from the bigger cell. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it in R (it may be useful, because I want to do this operation for many folders)

Could you help me?

Comment: some sample data or at least a bit more information would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, all I can tell you is to look into `matplotlib`, specifically the `hist()` function. 
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

Answer (score 1):

In R, it's much the same as in Python:

```
hist(data)
```

There is a useful introduction to the raster package in the vignette:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf